# How to use mongoskin $pull to remove an array member, based on the value of a property in that member?

Tags: mongodb

Given a document structure like this:

```
{
_id : <someid>,
items : [
          {prop1 : 0, prop2: 1, prop3 : 1 },
          {prop1 : 1, prop2: 1, prop3 : 2 },
          {prop1 : 1, prop2: 2, prop3 : 1 }
        ]
}
```

**How would I pull each of the items with prop1 = 1?** (i.e. in this case remove the last two items.

I've tried:

```
.....update({'_id': someid}, {$pull: {'items.prop1': 1}},{ multi: true });
```

but that does not seem to be working as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
{$pull : {'items' : {'prop1': 1} }}
db.test.update({}, {$pull : {'items' : {'prop1': 1} }} )
```

Comment: But I only want to update the document with the correct id - this query doesn't select the document id right?

Comment: I just gave you the hint, I didn't write the complete query. Here it is: db.test.update({'_id': someid}, {$pull : {'items' : {'prop1': 1} }})